# Fill holes of a binary mask fails twice

Tags: python, scipy

I have a little problem filling holes of a binary mask (NIfTI file). Here are code snippet as well as a picture of the input mask and the in 2 directions distorted, incompletely filled result mask:

```
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk
from scipy import ndimage

mask = sitk.ReadImage(path)
data = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(mask)

for z in range(data.shape[2]):
    data[:,:,z] = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(data[:,:,z])

mask = sitk.GetImageFromArray(data.astype(int))

sitk.WriteImage(mask, path[:-7] + '_filled.nii.gz')
```

[image]
[image]

If I don't apply the function to each slice in z-direction, but directly to the whole image, it doesn't get better. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do the slices look like for the incompletely-filled z-values? Are the holes actually closed? As for the distortion, it looks like displayed location is different in the second image, so you may need to copy some metadata about the resolution and units from the original image when writing it out.